# Protocol being called in two different classes at same time

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols, presenter

I am a little new to iOS development, coming from a Java / Android background. My understanding is that your custom `Protocols` or `Delegates` are like `Interfaces` in Java land.

If that is the case then I believe these `Protocols` are also `Objects` as well.

#### Case:

- Assume 2 `ViewController`s, `Home` and `Profile`.
- 1 `Presenter`, let's call it `StuffPresenter` gets instantiated individually in both `ViewController`s.
- `StuffPresenter` has an initialization method called `initWithInteractor` that takes in a parameter of `Interactor` which is a protocol.
- Both Home and Profile implement a `Protocol` called Interactor, which has a method called `initStuffInTableView(NSMutableArray *)stuff`.

So I have a dilemma where if I am in `Home` and `StuffPresenter` relays information then I switch over to `Profile`, `StuffPresenter` loads stuff in `Home` as well as `Profile`.

Why is this the case?

Here is the code I have setup:

**Protocol**

```
@protocol Interactor <NSObject>

- (void)initStuffInTableView:(NSMutableArray *)stuff;

@end
```

**Presenter**

```
@interface Presenter : NSobject

- (id)initWithInteractor:(id<Interactor>)interactor;
- (void)loadStuff;

@end

@implementation {
    @private
    id<Interactor> _interactor;
}

- (id)initWithInteractor:(id<Interactor>)interactor {
    _interactor = interactor;
    return self;
}

- (void)loadStuff {
    // Load stuff 
    NSMutableArray *stuff = // Init stuff in array...
    [_interactor initStuffInTableView:stuff];
}

@end
```

**Home**

```
@interface HomeViewController : UITableViewController <Interactor>

- (void)initPresenter;

@end

@implementation {
    @private
    StuffPresenter *_stuffPresenter;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self initPresenter];
    [self initPullToRefresh];
}

# pragma mark - init

- (void)initPresenter {
    _stuffPresenter = [[StuffPresenter alloc] initWithInteractor:self];
}

- (void)initPullToRefresh {
    // Init pull to refresh
    // ...
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self
                            action:@selector(reloadStuff)
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

# pragma mark - Interactor

- (void)initStuffInTableView:(NSMutableArray *)stuff {
    // Do some work
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

# pragma mark - reloadStuff

- (void)reloadStuff {
    [_stuffPresenter loadStuff];
}

# pragma mark - TableView methods here

// TableView methods...

@end
```

**Profile**

```
@interface ProfileViewController : UITableViewController <Interactor>

- (void)initPresenter;

@end

@implementation {
    @private
    StuffPresenter *_stuffPresenter;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self initPresenter];
}

# pragma mark - init

- (void)initPresenter {
    _stuffPresenter = [[StuffPresenter alloc] initWithInteractor:self];
    [_stuffPresenter loadStuff];
}

# pragma mark - Interactor

- (void)initStuffInTableView:(NSMutableArray *)stuff {
    // Do some work
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

# pragma mark - TableView methods here

// TableView methods...

@end
```

#### Problem:

When I go to `Profile` the app crashes, because `initStuffInTableView` is being called in `Home`. Why is this the case?

Comment: Minor point: methods should only start with the word `init` if they are initializers which call to `[super init..]`. And they should only be called during initial allocation/instantiation.

Comment: Thanks for the point, I am used to being able to setup different constructors in `Java` how would I best accomplish that in `Objective C` land? My understanding was that I could setup custom `initWith<key-word>` methods.

Comment: You can still have different constructors, I'm just saying you shouldn't use `init` for a method that isn't a constructor/initializer :)  See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Initialization.html) and [here](https://blog.twitter.com/2014/how-to-objective-c-initializer-patterns)

Comment: Ahh okay you are referring to my custom initializer methods like `initPresenter`, `initPullToRefresh` yea that makes sense.

Comment: I think ill just name those methods as `setup<key-word>` going forward.

Comment: What is the crash/exception message?  None of the discussion around method naming etc is actually going to solve your problem...but the objective-C convention wouldn't be to have a method at all, but simply expose a property and assign a value to it (which does call the property's setter), so you would probably create a method called `setPresenter` or do nothing and just let the compiler handle it

Comment: The crash exception is that both table views in Home and Profile are being called. See answer below for my solution. Can you explain to me why StuffPresenter gets called in both ViewControllers?

Answer (score 1):

A `protocol` is an Objective-C language feature for specifying that a Class (or another protocol) has certain features, for the benefit of the compiler/ARC/the programmer.

A `delegate`, or delegation, is a design pattern which makes Model View Controller easier. To make the object doing the delegation be more flexible, generally its delegate adopts a protocol.

There are a number of issues in your code:

1. Your Presenter has a reference cycle with its interactors
2. You need to call some `init` method that eventually calls `[super init]` in your Presenter's `initWithInteractor:` method.
3. As others have pointed out, your methods which begin with `init` violate Objective-C conventions.

It's hard to tell from what you've posted exactly what your problem is, but I'm *very* suspicious of how it's structured.

You have a single class (Presenter), which you make two instances of, and pass no parameters other than the Interactor.

How could each instance know to load different "stuff" based on which View controller it received as a parameter?

Comment: If you're familiar with the model view presenter pattern that is what I am deploying above, of course those are not the ONLY methods that would be in the presenter. Let's assume that we have an entity called `Stuff` then `StuffPresenter` would handle presenting and sending data for anything related to `Stuff`. My idea is to keep view controllers related only to controlling and presenting views. Thus preventing massive view controllers.

Comment: Since you have critiques about my code care to post more specific examples on how to fix it? For example please provide a more thorough example of point 2.). Also explain point 1.) in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I still want to understand thoroughly what is going on here, but I did solve the problem by doing the following.

In both `Home` and `Profile`, I init the `StuffPresenter` here:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animation];
    [self initPresenter];
}
```

And when exiting a controllerview I do the following:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    _stuffPresenter = nil;
}
```